# ActionBar Theme is ignored

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

This is strange.
I'm trying to change color of ActionBar using themes.
Here's my code for styles.xml in values:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/TheActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

    </style>

    <style name="TheActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#1f1f2f</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

And for styles.xml in values-14:

```
    <resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/TheActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>

       <style name="TheActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#1f1f2f</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I use requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR); in MainActivity

But the color of ActionBar doesn't change - it is standart. Where did I screw up?

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem , I am sharing a xml style code to you check that.

```
<style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#693EB4</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

In this code sample I have made a new style for action bar in style.xml, in this `colorPrimary` is small top bar(StatusBar) color and `colorPrimary` dark is the color of ActionBar, so you need to change this color.
And the parent value is the type of action bar theme you want.